# DBA_MVIEWS: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, long-integer, clob

I want to view the "QUERY" column of the DBA_MVIEWS table as a simple TEXT.

If I execute the following statement:

```
select to_lob(query) from dba_mviews;
```

I have the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG
```

I have no errors with this instead:

```
select query from dba_mviews;
```

But I obtain a CLOB result in DBVisualizer.

I'm using:

- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
- Product: DbVisualizer Pro 10.0.15 [Build #2861]
- OS: Mac OS X
- OS Version: 10.14.1
- OS Arch: x86_64
- Java Version: 1.8.0_172

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

[From the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_LOB.html) (emphasis added):

> `TO_LOB` converts `LONG` or `LONG RAW` values in the column `long_column` to `LOB` values. You can apply this function only to a `LONG` or `LONG RAW` column, **and only in the select list of a subquery in an `INSERT` statement**.

So you can't use it in a simple query, as you are trying to do. And creating a table to insert the query strings into probably isn't very helpful or practical for you.

Handling `long` values is generally a bit of a pain. You can convert them to CLOBs in a PL/SQL block, e.g.:

```
declare
  l_long long;
  l_clob clob;
begin
  select query into l_long from dba_mviews;
  l_clob := to_clob(l_long);
  -- do something with l_clob
end;
/
```

... but that also probably isn't very useful here, even if you make a function that returns a pipelined CLOB.

The [DBVisualizer docs](http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG91/Editing+Table+Data#EditingTableData-EditingBinary/BLOBandCLOBData) say:

> Due to the nature of binary/BLOB and CLOB data, cells of these types can only be fully modified and viewed in the Cell Editor. (There is partial support in the Form Editor to view image data and to load from file).
>
> In the grid, Binary/BLOB and CLOB data is by default presented by an icon and the size of the value. You can select another presentation format in the Tools Properties dialog, in the Grid / Binary/BLOB and CLOB Data category under the General tab. Selecting By Value results in performance penalties and the memory consumption increases dramatically.

This isn't a tool I've used, but it sounds like it's treating and displaying the `long` value as it would a CLOB already, so hopefully this still applies.

Comment: Thanks, very useful

Comment: To be fair, it is really a poor show that Oracle have got to 18c and they **still** haven't done something about the LONG columns in the data dictionary. Heaven knows they charge for the licences, they ought to do something about it.